# Routed Event Args with ButtonBase

Tags: wpf-controls, dependency-properties, routed-events

I am currently working on a program with a team of members and they don't know how to solve this either. I created a set of specialty user controls "ImageButton". I am using that for the menu section of the program. The menu itself is another user control.

They are currently using ButtonBase.Click to access the buttons, but it doesn't work with my new ImageButtons.

The ButtonBase.Click leads to an event called "MainMenu_Click".

private void MainMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button _menuButtonClicked = (Button)e.OriginalSource;
            this.ShowMainPage((MainMenuCommands)_menuButtonClicked.Tag);
        }

I have already tried parsing them as ImageButtons but it has not worked. So I need a solution that is similar to ButtonBase.Click but for my ImageButtons.

Edit:
There are 3 files I am working with:
MainWindow.xaml (and its cs)
MainMenu.xaml (and its cs)
ImageButton.xaml (and its cs)

MainMenu has several ImageButtons on it. MainMenu is used on MainWindow. One of the properties to set is ButtonBase.Click. But I need that to be setup for ImageButtons not System.Windows.Controls.Button.

Comment: Not sure what your question is.  Do you mean "how do I implement a click event on my ImageButton"?

Comment: There is already a click event for my ImageButton. The problem is that I cannot get the function above to work due to a parsing issue. I need to be able to set a ButtonBase.Click property for my ImageButton that is parsed as an ImageButton type.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make your ImageButton derive from ButtonBase (or Button) -- then you'll get all of ButtonBase such as its events like Click.  It's actually quite simple to do this.  I have a RibbonButton that's like an image button which derives from Button as a custom control.  You write the template in Generic.xaml to set the look, then add any other properties and code.

Comment: The one it is already setup by is ImageButton : UserControl in the cs file. Do I just change the UserControl to Button?

Comment: I should probably note, my boss wants it as a usercontrol.

Comment: You need to change it to a Button or a custom control based on ButtonBase.  You cannot use ButtonBase.Click on a UserControl because ButtonBase.Click is only defined for ButtonBase; it's not an attached property.

Comment: Okay I still not getting this. I tried changing at the `public partial class ImageButton : UserControl` to` public partial class ImageButton : Button` but it did not work.  My superior does not wanting me to use custom controls at all, just user control

Comment: You can't just change the class declaration, that won't work.  You must use a custom control based on Button or ButtonBase.  There is no workaround to get what you want.